# PEAR Installer won't upgrade

Tags: php, ssh, dreamhost, pear, soap

I'm trying to install SOAP on PEAR via the command line on Dreamhost. I've upgraded to the latest version of PEAR (1.9.0) but when I try and install SOAP I get the error:

> pear/SOAP requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.5.4), installed version is 1.5.0

I've tried everything I can think of to upgrade, but can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: You say PEAR is at v 1.9.0, but the error says PEAR is at v. 1.5.0.

Comment: Yeah, and therein lies the problem. I try to install 1.9.0 and it tells me that that version or newer is already installed, but when I try and instal SOAP it tells me I'm on 1.5.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pear upgrade` to upgrade PEAR itself:

```
pear upgrade PEAR
```

or:

```
pear upgrade-all
```

Comment: [mario]$ pear upgrade PEAR
pear/PEAR is already installed and is newer than detected release version 1.9.0
[...]
upgrade failed
[mario]$ pear install SOAP
WARNING: "pear/HTTP_Request" is deprecated in favor of "pear/H"
Did not download optional dependencies: [...], use --alldeps to download automatically
pear/SOAP requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.5.4), installed version is 1.5.0
pear/SOAP can optionally use package "pear/Mail"
pear/SOAP can optionally use package "pear/Mail_Mime"
pear/SOAP can optionally use package "pear/Net_DIME"
No valid packages found
install failed

Answer (score 1):

Got in touch with Dreamhost and they say it's a problem with their setup:

> Ah. Yea. The reason why the version does not match is due to back porting
>   done in the Debian version we're using. I'm not sure if there's a way
>   around that but can create a incident report with our system admin if
>   you'd like. But ultimately, it would be best to install a custom copy of
>   PHP and PEAR in order to install custom modules.